# jQuery tabs preventDefailt one particular tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to prevent default one tab.

This is the tab:

```
<li class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" 
 aria-controls="Preferences" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
 <a href="#Preferences" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">Preferences</a></li>
```

This is my javascript.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$('#ui-id-2').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

The a link eventlistener works, but the event does not get prevented. Is there a way I can preventDefault behavior on one tab?

Comment: What behavior? Remove the href

Comment: Did you try `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false;` in the click handler?

Comment: @freedomn-m those did not seem to work because `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` probably overrides the event listener.

Comment: Can you detail *exactly* which plugin you are using for `.tabs()`?  It's not part of jquery, but could be the jquery-ui version or some other random plugin.  If it's jquery-ui, then just handle the `beforeActive()` event: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that do you want to do is prevent the "Preferences" tab can be open.
So you can use the property "disabled" the value of this property is for default false, you can set it to true for disabled all the tabs or set an array to indicate index tabs that are disabled

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs (
   { disabled: [ 2 ] }
);
```

the code above disable the 3rd tab
And remember for these cases you can´t use the preventDefault() function, because it´s not a default behavior of the component

Comment: What is the syntax if I want an if before disabling that tab?

Comment: There's no `if` in your question, only disabling the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent default behavior via `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`, both ways are valid. For example, here I've created 3 links, they are totally the same except `id` and handling events:

1. Normal link
2. Prevent default behavior via `event.preventDefault()`
3. Prevent default behavior via `return false`

```js
$('#ui-id-2').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});

$('#ui-id-3').click(function(event) {
   return false;
});
```

```css
li {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" 
 aria-controls="Preferences" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
 <a href="https://www.google.ru/?hl=en" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1">Preferences</a></li>

<li class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" 
 aria-controls="Preferences" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
 <a href="https://www.google.ru/?hl=en" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">Preferences</a></li>
 
<li class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" 
 aria-controls="Preferences" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
 <a href="https://www.google.ru/?hl=en" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-3">Preferences</a></li>
```

Comment: I think that `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` function overrides my event listener and I cannot prevent default of that tab.

Comment: @zerociudo I don't see this part in provided code, but yes, it's possible. Try to comment that line temporarily